# stopActivityUpdates function doesn't stop coreMotion if I set it to nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

In the code below, doing  `self?.motionActivityManager?.stopActivityUpdates()` doesn't stop/end `motionActivityManger` from processing. It still continues.

```
motionActivityManager?.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) {
    [weak self] activity in

    if activity?.walking == true {
        self?.motionActivityManager?.stopActivityUpdates()
        self?.motionActivityManager = nil
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** If remove `self?.motionActivityManager = nil` then it stops as it should...why is that?

Comment: Try making the call on the main thread.

Comment: @ryantxr didn't make a difference

Comment: You are doing a lot of optional chaining. Are you sure all of those optionals are not `nil`?

Comment: @rmaddy if your question was meant to ask "if I'm actually hitting the `stopActivityUpdates`...then yes it does reach to that. From what I see all values are non-nil and once I remove `self?.motionActivityManager = nil` then it works as it should